# json4s query on a parsed spark json stream

Tags: json, apache-spark, spark-streaming, json4s

I am trying to use the json4s to parse and query through a stream in spark.
I can parse the stream to org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream[org.json4s.JValue].
But when I try to use the query feature I seem to fail at browsing using "\\".

Below is the error I get. Why could this be ?

```
 [info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /home/../target/scala-2.10/classes...
 [error] /home/../src/main/test.scala:90: value \\ is not a member of org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream[org.json4s.JValue]
 [error]    JArray(ips) <- jsValue \\ "ips"
```

And here is my scala code

```
val jsValue1 = for {
JArray(ips) <- jsValue \\ "ips"
JObject(ip) <- ips
JField("ipaddress", JString(ipaddress))<- ip
}yield ipaddress
```

I am using json4s.native

```
import org.json4s._
import org.json4s.native.JsonParser
import org.json4s.native.JsonMethods._
```

When I do below I get : value \\ is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.json4s.JValue]

```
messages.foreachRDD { rdd =>
val jsValue = rdd.map{ case (v,_) => implicit val formats = DefaultFormats; JsonParser.parse(v)}
val jsValue1 = for {
JArray(ips) <- jsValue \\ "ips"
JObject(ip) <- ips
JField("ipaddress", JString(ipaddress)) <- ip
}yield ipaddress}
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: you are iterating on the DSStream?

Comment: I parse my KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](
      ssc, kafkaParams, topicsSet) with JsonParser.parse(). I get a JObject(List((...)) at the end

Comment: what about foreachRDD => map to parse your json?

Comment: Now I get: value \ is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.json4s.JValue]

Comment: You have to map on that RDD (e.g RDD[org.json4s.JValue])

Comment: Is this wrong : messages.foreachRDD { rdd =>
 val jsValue = rdd.map{ case (v,_) => implicit val formats = DefaultFormats; JsonParser.parse(v)}
 val jsValue1 = for {
 JArray(ips) <- jsValue \\ "ips"
 JObject(ip) <- ips
 JField("ipaddress", JString(ipaddress)) <- ip
 }yield ipaddress }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92529/discussion-between-etr-and-eliasah).